# SQL server Express 2017 LocalDB

Tags: silent-installer, sql-server-2017-express

As far as I know LocalDB direct download is not available for SQL Server Express 2017. Now, If I donwload "SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe" from "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853017", it shows options (Basic,Custom, Download Media) and wait for user action. But, I would like to know what parameters  I can provide for innosetup in order to download ExpressCore localDB directly?

Comment: Well, If I download from the above mentioned link, it downloads the file with the name "SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe",  do you know the link to download Sql Server 2017 Express and the file name should be like this "SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" ?

Comment: Actually, I need the parameters that I can mention in the innosetup file for silent installation in order to avoid those options (Basic,Custom, Download Media).